# this.style.cursor='hand', not working for the first time when I hover mouse on to the element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to programming. All I was trying is to change the style of cursor to hand **onmouseover** event. when I run the page for first time it is changing the border style but the cursor style is not being changed, but when I move the cursor onto the image element for the second time everything is working as expected. 
can anyone please explain what's the exact reason for this improper behavior and how can I make it work.

**NOTE:**
I was trying to implement this in asp.net content pages :P so I feel this is easier way instead of maintaining a separate css file

```
<img alt="Sedan" width="300px" height="200px" id="img" src="Images/WelcomePage/Compact/abc.jpg" />


<script>
    img.onmouseover = function () {
        this.style.cursor = 'hand';
        this.style.border = "2px solid black"
    }
    img.onmouseout = function () {
        this.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        this.style.border = "2px solid white"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can do this with pure CSS, why use JS for this?

Comment: Also, `hand` is not a valid value, you need to use `pointer` on mouseover and `default` on mouseout

Comment: I was trying to implement this in asp.net content pages :P so I feel this is easier way instead of maintaining a separate css file.

Comment: It's not about easier, its about doing it in a right way and an effective way. I didn't answered cuz I was not sure about your technical constraints but if you are open to equivalent CSS solution I'll be happy to share one

Comment: And it's not like it's easier, either. You don't need a separate .css file (though that's usually best). If you insist on doing it inline, a `style` element is no harder than a `script` element. One of the rules about being new to something is to pay attention to what people with more experience are telling you. So "Oh, how would I do it with CSS without creating a separate file?" rather than "I feel this is easier way instead of maintaining a separate css file." Be aware of what you don't know.

Comment: I know how to implement this in css,  I was trying to dig out  if there is any possibility to implement this in javascript. Thanks for your response guys :)

Comment: Agree with Crowder here, also make sure you optimize your code in a basic way, say you can cache your element in a variable so using `this` keyword every time, assign it to a variable.. and than use that variable to take actions on that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I  know how to implement this in css, I was trying to dig out if there is any possibility to implement this in javascript.

Well, that was important information to include in the question.

Two things:

1. You need to use the correct [CSS `cursor` property values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#propdef-cursor), `hand` is not a valid value.
2. You need to ensure that your code runs *after* the image exists. The easiest way to do that is to put your `script` tag at the end of your HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

If you do those things, it works. Of course, the image moves because it doesn't initially have a border:

```js
img.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  this.style.border = "2px solid black";
}
img.onmouseout = function() {
  this.style.cursor = 'default';
  this.style.border = "2px solid white";
}
```

```html
<img alt="Sedan" width="300px" height="200px" id="img" src="Images/WelcomePage/Compact/abc.jpg" />
```

I don't recommend relying on the automatic global (the one created because you have `id="img"`), but it does work.

---

As [kaiido points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774252/this-style-cursor-hand-not-working-for-the-first-time-when-i-hover-mouse-on-t/33774487?noredirect=1#comment55316757_33774487), we could just set the `cursor` property once rather than in the event handlers, since it only applies when the cursor is hovering the element anyway:

```js
img.style.cursor = 'pointer';
img.onmouseover = function() {
  this.style.border = "2px solid black";
}
img.onmouseout = function() {
  this.style.border = "2px solid white";
}
```

```html
<img alt="Sedan" width="300px" height="200px" id="img" src="Images/WelcomePage/Compact/abc.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Crowder very helpful.

Comment: I was going to upvote since this is the only one that answer "why isn't this code working" until I realised that nowhere you stated that this is a totally useless code since the CSS `cursor` property has only effect when hovering the element (which means that you could just set it once to `"pointer"` and only change the `border` one on mouseout/leave). Nah.. upvoting anyway...

Comment: @Kaiido: LOL, good point! But at least the border needs the handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Try using CSS instead of JavaScript. If you want to do it in the same file, use a `style` element:

```
<style>
#img {
    border: 2px solid white;
}
#img:hover{
    cursor: pointer ;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
```

That gives the image a white border normally (with the default cursor), then changes it to black with the pointer cursor when the mouse is over the element.